# Rebuilding (a wee bit) after "Not a real question": finding gems and burning garbage

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've been thinking a bit about what impact "Not a real question" had on the site for a little while, so I threw together a query to figure it out.

The results are...surprising, to say the least.  There are ~43.6K questions closed with the reason, but a small handful of them are objective, on-topic, or helpful to others (characterized mostly by view count and votes).

The query to see those potential questions [is right here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/399512/all-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-potential-hidden-gems).   There's a good chance that some of these need to be deleted too, but there are some of them that just need to be edited into shape to bring it in line with the rest of the content we hold in high esteem.

There's also some obviously wild and off-topic questions there which aren't actionable because they are used as dupe targets.

Of course, there are the clunkers out there as well.  These are the questions the roomba didn't do any justice to and it *should* have.  The query to see those questions [is right here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398423/all-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-potential-clunkers).  That's not to say that *all* of them are terrible, but *most* of them definitely do not belong.

I've brought this to everyone's attention to see if there's anything we could or should do as a community to address this problem.  Obviously, there's a lot of questions here that need to be edited or deleted, and one can't do it alone.  But, if there are any questions that are actually good out there, I don't want to lose them to the noise of it being closed as "not a real question".

Thoughts?  At the bare minimum, I hope to have come away from this with at least some new life into what the roomba should be pinpointing, since deleting questions with little impact should be handled by it.

Comment: Ah, yes, them goode olde Atwoode years.  When I had three quick selections for ["this is sand"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).  Why anybody would want to pick through a garbage pile of sand laced with rotten banana peels and an occasional usable old couch is quite beyond me.  Can't you find enough entertainment in the triage queue?

Comment: @HansPassant:  The point was to draw attention to the fact that, perhaps the roomba needs to be strengthened to get *rid* of those banana peels.  Not just that, but it also scratches an itch of mine to see how popular some of those "not a real question" questions actually turned out to be.  If they're truly rubbish, we as normal users shouldn't even be bothered with their existence, which is what I'm calling out.

Comment: But the couch, @HansPassant! THE COUCH!

Comment: Also, if a lot of people are getting some usage out of the old couch, it's worth the time to Febreeze it anyway.

Comment: @Makoto You're gonna need a lot more than Febreze, I fear. Possibly some fire. And by "some" I mean "a lot".

Comment: @IanKemp:  Oh, I know I need a lot of fire for this.  Problem is I ran out of kerosene about 5 minutes into it.  I do believe that there are some really good questions hidden amongst the noise, but I don't think I can do anything about it myself.  Hence, the question:  is it even worth bothering?