# Let's rescue wayward resource requests! (trial run)

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, recommendation-questions

A few months, back, [Stijn raised the issue of old, closed resource-requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337425/questions-closed-for-recommending-finding-an-off-site-resource-should-be-deleted):

> When searching for a library/tool/... with my favourite search engine, there are often results from Stack Overflow. Since these questions are (in theory) closed and/or outdated, they pollute my search results and cause annoyance.

In spite of his odd spelling of "favorite", I had to concede his point; these often *are* a nuisance. But... Some of them are also useful. So [I asked the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337425/questions-closed-for-recommending-finding-an-off-site-resource-should-be-deleted/337460#337460),

> What, if anything, is worth saving here? And how do we go about saving it?

...I guess that probably seemed rhetorical, since I didn't really get much of an answer to it. So I started digging through some of the most popular, closed, resource-request questions on Stack Overflow. I found stuff that [wasn't really looking for a resource so much as a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/how-can-i-profile-c-code-running-in-linux), stuff that *was* looking for a resource but [*got* a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux), [basic HOWTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad), [weird-ass Android stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769762/web-colors-in-an-android-color-xml-resource-file), and, of course, straight-up [give me a tool to do something of which there are innumerable tools available with no criteria to filter the list whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424278/tool-to-draw-er-diagrams). (That last link is now deleted, of course - you can probably guess why.)

About three years ago, we launched a site for Software Recommendations. If you look at their [Ask a Question page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) today, off to the right you'll find five succinct rules for asking a question there... Four of which are pretty decent rules for asking a good question *anywhere*:

> Tell us...

> 1. ...the task you want to accomplish
> 2. ...your requirements for that task
> 3. ...what you already know about software available for this purpose

> Then, write a specific and to-the-point title

With those rules in mind, I edited three of the five questions mentioned above, and reopened them. (One I deleted and the remaining question I locked)

Only problem is... There are a lot more than five of these questions still visible on the site.

### I need a posse

So here's what I'd like to try: at the end of this post is a list of 200 questions currently closed on Stack Overflow, a bit less than 1% of the total list. Let's see if we can use the Software Recs guidelines to turn some of these into questions that can be kept around, as sort of a trial run before we try & tackle the much larger backlog.

If you want to help,

1. Pick a question off the list
2. Ensure it has answer that are more than just links to things
3. Edit it to comply with the four rules mentioned above.
4. Remove any language that explicitly asks for an off-site recommendation (software, hardware, tutorial, etc.)
5. Vote to reopen
6. Edit this post to move the link into the "to be reopened" list below.

If you have less than 3K reputation, you can't complete all of these steps.  Should this prove successful, [a way to open this up to others will be looked into.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run#comment435513_341987)

If you pick a question and find it impossible to finish the steps above, then edit this post to move the link into the "to be deleted" list, with a short explanation of why you saw it as unsalvageable.

There's also a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133688) to discuss on individual post, feel free to join if you want to participate but still have doubts.

When the first list is empty, we'll go through the other two lists & see if it's worth continuing with this project.

Oh, and feel free to write about your experience in the answers below.

---

##Questions to be reviewed (see instructions above)

### Questions to be reopened

### Questions reopened (45/200)

```
Simple data validation
How to serialize data in C
Ways to deploying console applications in C#
How to use Robotium with Android Studio?
Creating Excel (.xlsx) files in Cocoa
Generating an image of a database schema used in a Rails app
Big data visualization using “search, show context, and expand on demand” concept
How to debug JavaScript code with mobile browsers
Improve SOAP UI performace
How to implement autocomplete In JavaScript
Pure Java HTML viewer/renderer for use in a Scrollable pane
Stress testing more than 10000 browser instances with Selenium
Checking for code plagiarism with JavaScript
Convert video Input Stream to RTMP
How to get the full PHP documentation offline
Make the default android emulator faster
HTML select drop-down with an input field
Data Grid for Angular 2?
Structuring online documentation for a REST API All link-only answers
How can I profile C++ code running in Linux? 
Shelve is too slow for large dictionaries, what can I do to improve performance?
What are some techniques I could use to help gain a better understanding of how the concepts in discrete math are used in programming?
How can I beautify JSON for display in a TextBox?
Access webcam without Flash
Converting punycode with dash character to Unicode
How to write an RSS feed in Java
How could I graphically display the memory layout from a .map file?
Prevent MediaWiki from being spammed
Render a PDF file using Java in Android
Minimal implementation of sprintf or printf
Monitor the Graphics card usage
Dubugging PostScript
Manage code snippets in Notepad++
Desktop notifications from GitHub
Storing and querying JSON from a database
How to format/tidy/beautify in JavaScript
Built-in method for evaluating math expressions in Java
How to manage license banners in source files of Eclipse plug-in projects
Working with huge files in VIM
Batch decompiling of Java files with JD-GUI
How do I find a list of Homebrew's installable packages?
Best way to save & restore a form? (FOSS)
Is there an open source CSS validator that can be run locally?
ImageMagick vs GraphicsMagick
MASM under Linux?
```

### Questions to be deleted

### Questions deleted (155/200)

```
Do free plugins exist that could replace resharper? Cannot be made on-topic, answer is no
Best HTML5 Canvas Library for Super Mario Platform Game? Too broad, list of links
Need a simple WYSIWYG editor with image upload Too broad, list of links
Maven dependency incompatible license check plugin Too broad, list of links
Highlight git uncommitted files and folders on sublime text2 folder pane? Too broad, list of links
Python documentation generator Too broad, list of links
PHP + Quickbooks integration (API) Too broad, list of links
Ruby CMS/blog: Mephisto vs. Radiant Primarily opinion based, list of opinions
Anyone knows a matplotlib equivalent in C or C++ Too broad, list of links
Setting up Git server on Windows? Too broad, list of links
Is there a Linux Debugger (with GUI) like Ollydbg for Windows? Too broad, list of links
c++ projects for beginners Too broad
Windows batch: 'tee' command Too broad
Simple AI Programming Too broad
Online WebGL GLSL Shader editor Too broad, list of links
Linux-alternative to Fiddler2 Too broad, list of links
Webgl 2D engine? Too broad, list of links
Can you recommend a charting library for Scala? Too broad, list of links
Eclipse Java Profiler Too broad, list of links
Alternative for PC-Lint supporting C++14 (Visual Studio 2013) Too broad, list of links
Scientific Library Options for C or C++ Too broad and primarily opinion based, list of links and opinions
STM32 compiler/debugger chain? Too broad and primarily opinion based, list of links and opinions
Software for multiple copy/paste? Too broad, list of links
Windows native GUI programming on C++ Too broad, list of links
Free JProfiler alternatives Too broad, list of links
Commandline Jabber client Too broad, list of links
JavaScript and CSS minimizer Too broad, list of links
Static Comments System for Jekyll Too broad, list of links
PHP Logging framework? Too broad, list of links
Generate ER diagram from postgres-sql database \[on OSX Snow Leopard\] Too broad, list of links
Free plugin FTP/SFTP for Sublime Text General computing
How to use VCC with C++ Tried to make it on-topic but it is no longer relevant
Any good (open-source) alternative to SharePoint? can't be reworded, I tried
API for stock price? 
NAT Traversal Too broad by several orders of magnitude
Any automated way to convert CoffeeScript to ES6? All link-only answers
Java EE for beginners Primarily opinion-based
Twig vs Smarty. Benchmark  Request for a benchmark with an opinion based answer
Where can I find open source Youtube-like software? Too Broad
Is there any simple tutorial or a source to learn Apache-Camel? Tutorial request; Too Broad
Recommend a Python library to read Excel XLS files Fixing would make it a duplicate of the linked questions
Is there a Google Play Music API? All link-only answers
Is there a github-like site for internal use? Nothing but links.
What are some popular OCR algorithms? Too broad. Mostly just link-only answers and naming of other things to research.
Scala CheatSheet Quickref Cheat sheet request; all answers link-only.
jekyll with wysiwyg "Does something like this exist already?"
Framework for beginners Primarily opinion-based.
How to learn flex? Very broad; answers are nothing but links.
auto clean python source code All link-only answers
Is there an Open Source licence matrix? Off-topic.
What tools do you design software with? Too broad.
Is there a tool like phpMyAdmin for MongoDB databases? All link-only answers
Free barcode scanner SDK for iOS (iPhone) Duplicate if made on-topic
Which is the most mature Python XMPP library for a GChat client? unsalvageable, no good answers
DurandalJS vs AngularJS? primarily opinon based
Any good user management framework for Node.js All link-only answers
CAD like 3D geometry C/C++ library Most answers are link-only and have very few upvotes. Not useful.
Where can I find a video of a professional using Emacs? Off-topic
IDE for Common Lisp (for windows and linux) cannot make it not a resource request
Lightweight PHP library alternative to common MVC frameworks cannot make it not a resource request
Is there any open source OCR project for the iPhone out there? does not describe a task to be accomplished
RTMP C# Client library too broad if made on-topic
Best database for small applications and tools does not describe a task to be accomplished
Rich text HTML editor for websites I can use for free? too broad
Know of a country-nationality list for DB lookup table? too broad
OAuth 2.0 Service Provider .NET libraries cannot make it not a resource request
any sample MySQL databases I can download? cannot make it not a resource request
Is there a unicode character for this symbol? (the "move" cursor) request for a single unicode symbol
Is there any tutorial out there on key value coding and Key Value Observing? tutorial request, too broad if made on-topic
Version control for binaries cannot make it not a resource request
Anyone know of a decent editable combo box plugin? list of links
Resources for TDD on Android does not describe a task, list of links
Google Maps API V3 in Android All link-only answers
Learning CSS, the proper & serious way! Recommending tutorials, link-only answers and primarily-opinion based
template engine for .NET environment Cannot be rephrased out of being a resource request
How to display pressed keyboard shortcuts on screen during presentations or screencasts? Off-topic. Not related to programming
Are there any studies comparing Java EE vs. .NET? Repairing the question would make it too opinion-based
Face detection in java Too broad if made on-topic
Is there any tool which can a resize png image into a image for ldpi , mdpi, hdpi and xdpi screen de Not programming related
PostgreSQL design tools similar to MySQL Workbench? All link-only answers
Ruby NLP Libraries Cannot be made on-topic
@font-face alternative for Myriad Pro? Cannot be made on-topic
SQL Server GUI For Linux All link-only answers
What are some good Java RDF libraries Cannot be made on-topic. Mostly link-only answers
Best resource for serious Commodore 64 programming All are just link-only or book recommendations
Is there a C# equivalent of Sonar? All link-only answers
Is there any service similar to TestFlight for Android that collects all client exception and show t All link-only answers
What are some good free/open-source HTML5/Flash video players? Too broad if made on-topic.
Recommended Vim plugins for C coding? Too broad, opinion-based, mostly just links
PGP Library for C#? List of links, too broad - needs moderator intervention to delete due to it being a dupe target
An ORM for sqlite.net for small applications All link-only answers
Text editor for editing files over ssh General computing
Best tool to do combinatorial/pairwise testing? Opinion-based
Is there anything similar to SQLAlchemy? Cannot be made on-topic
Distributed Computing in C++? Too broad, list of links
Is there an Alternative to XSLT Cannot be made on-topic
Is there an alternative to History.js? Cannot be made on-topic
Best place to learn JStree Tutorial recommendation, can't be made on-topic
Code review tool for Bitbucket Cannot be made on-topic
Insightful resources for game engine architecture? Opinion-based, list of links
Erlang interpreter List of links, cannot be made on-topic
Is there is a website which allows me to test Perl online? List of links
Is there a better alternative to the Mongo shell? Cannot reproduce the problem, not worth saving
CSS formatter NOT based on CSS Tidy? List of links
Is there a table component in Angular Material? List of links
Good BitTorrent libraries in .NET? All link-only answers.
Does Alexa provide an API or is there another way to access domain ranks programmatically? List of links
PHP Source Code Analyzers List of links
Should I learn Python or Java to develop GUI apps for Ubuntu? Opinion-based
What IDE would be good for linux kernel driver development Opinion-based
REST/JSON Web Services Java EE Framework List of links
Open source Portmon List of links
Mono Cecil official documentation? Cannot be made on-topic
What unit testing framework fits backbone.js? List of links
ruby on rails state machines List of links
H2 database GUI Tool All link-only answers
A GitHub-like web platform which does not charge for making projects private? List of links.
pros and cons of XMPP servers Opinion-based
Is there a good IDE for SQLite? Opinionated and too broad
JavaScript I18n (internationalization) frameworks/libraries for client-side use? If edited into shape, it would turn into a duplicate of this older and more viewed question
Free XML Compare Tool Only asks for off-site resource; all answers are just links to such resources.
A good IIS Log Viewer for large log files? No consensus on a good edit for it could be reached
React is V, how about the M and C? Possibly could be made on-topic, but the only answer is very opinion-based.
Good (preferable free) learning resources / books for embedded C / C++ programmers List of links, too broad
Need a Fragments Example Too broad
What to use for version control with Visual Studio 2008 for inhouse projects? Popularity question
Textbased issue-tracker/todo list for Git? List of links.
Android as an SMS Gateway for integration with Web Application? List of links.
Create PDF 417 barcode in asp.net WEB Application List of links. The non-shopping answers do not solve the (off-topic) question.
C++ Editor, Compiler, Debugger on Windows ( Lighter than Visual Studio) List of links.
What's a good minimal server-side JavaScript framework? List of links.
Looking for a standalone and open source "Social Login" PHP Library List of links.
examples of interactive plots through python List of links.
What lightweight web MVC frameworks Java has? List of links.
what is the recommended python frameworks for distributed computing? List of links.
Step by step tutorial on setting up spring (MVC) in IntelliJ, how long should this take a seasoned d
Template Engines for Spring Framework
Viable alternative to XSLT?
What is a good resource for learning XSL? cannot be made on-topic
Is there an Eclipse plugin for JavaFX 2.0? list of links
in-terminal (ASCII) histograms tool cannot be made on-topic
Best Delphi Regex library primarily opinion based
Source Insight alternative for Linux list of links
sync sqlite across 'cloud' to multiple devices only useful answer is a parse.com answer, parse.com no longer exists
iOS Backend Server Solutions? cannot be made on-topic, no useful answers
Code Snippet Managers for OS X? cannot be made on-topic, list of links
best wavelet library for R cannot be made on-topic, list of links
Message Passing Concurrency Library for C? cannot be made on-topic, list of links
Where is the best online Javascript language documentation? cannot be made on-topic, list of links
I search for the offline version of Laravel 4 documentation cannot be made on-topic, list of links
Access C++ shared library from Java: JNI, JNA, CNI, or SWIG? primarily opinion based, list of opinions
API Documentation Theme or Template cannot be made on-topic, list of links
Is there an alternative tool to Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio? cannot be made on-topic, list of links
Dynamic SQL Java library too broad, list of links
Core Text tutorial too broad, list of links
Android GUI Frameworks too broad, list of links
Sliding and swiping through pages with JavaScript on iPad too broad, list of links
```

Comment: Are we touching the answers?

Comment: @approxiblue edit any post you feel could be improved as you would normally.

Comment: The discussion on individual posts is going to get out of hand in the comments quickly, so I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133688 "Wayward Resource Request Rescue Center") for discussion of individual posts.

Comment: I think "How to write an RSS feed in Java" should remain closed or be locked if the answer is really that valuable. The question is too broad, and before the edit it was just a resource request. Neither revision is a good example of an on-topic question. Haven't looked at any of the other Qs

Comment: "*In spite of his odd spelling of "favorite"*" \*my \*favourite

Comment: For what (little) it's worth, I've added an answer to [Minimal implementation of sprintf or printf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16647278) that includes an implementation that (I believe) meets the stated requirements. Now it just needs to be voted up enough that somebody might notice it before they give up and leave.

Comment: @Shog9 Just an FYI: "Favourite" is the preferred spelling in non-U.S. English-speaking countries. http://grammarist.com/spelling/favorite-favourite/

Comment: I know, @Keith. And I forgive you all. Well, most of you.

Comment: There seems to be a typo. The last section should have read "Martijn Pieters wish list".

Comment: Any plans to have another go?

Answer (score 26):

Here's my experience so far:

Most of these questions need to be deleted, but there are way more salvageable questions here than I expected. Right now, most of these are being deleted because of attracting only link-only answers, but if there is even one really good egg, we've been trying to save the question.

However, there will probably need to be a Stage 2 posse (likely of moderators) who go back through the reopened questions to delete all the link-only answers, because there are a ***lot*** of them. If we find a good answer, we've been trying to upvote it to the top.

It's actually pretty fun to go through this list of questions, especially with [help from chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133688/wayward-resource-request-rescue-center).

Comment: "If we find a good egg among link-only answers..." ...the right thing to do is to edit the linked content summary into it so that it's not a link-only anymore. This has proven to work really well, see [Cleanup 500 old terse answers that either have hidden value or indicate awful questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334866/839601)

Comment: @gnat The "good egg" answers usually already have a content summary, or they have code that shows how to use whatever software they are recommending. Sometimes there's even an answer that recommends not using an off-site resource, which we saw as really good also ([like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6086206/5743988)).

Comment: answers with content simply don't qualify as link-only ones, we have a fairly efficient criteria on that laid out in [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773): "strip the markup, and you still get at least a little bit of useful information..."

Comment: @gnat 4 castle is using the phrase "good egg" to describe answers that are not just a link.

Comment: ah, I got it @TinyGiant - thanks for explaining

Answer (score 14):

> Oh, and feel free to write about your experience in the answers below.

As @4castle said, most of the questions were as unsalvageable as I had predicted they would be. More surprising was the fact that there were far more salvageable questions than I had predicted there would be.

Saving questions felt rewarding. We successfully resurrected these wayward questions and allowed them to live and serve another day. We didn't worry about invalidating answers that consisted primarily of links or opinions, such answers don't hold much—if any—lasting value.

All in all, it was a pretty enjoyable process. For most questions that were unsalvageable, it was immediately obvious that the question wasn't going to be salvageable.

If you remove those questions from the equation, you're left with a few different types of questions:

- Questions that were never off-topic. These questions were mistakenly closed and didn't need any editing *to make them on-topic*. These questions were very rare.
- Questions that were edited to be on-topic after closure but never reopened. These were probably as rare as the previous type of question.
- Questions that were actually off-topic, but received a good answer and could be edited to fit that answer. As I said previously, we weren't worried about invalidating answers that consisted primarily of links or opinions. These were fairly common.
- Questions that were asking for tools, but the scope of the tasks being performed were reasonable enough to be the topic of a question. These questions were edited to be "How to" questions instead. These questions were also fairly common.
- Questions that were truly off-topic and could not be made on-topic, but still contained useful information. We tried getting wiki locks put on these, but it was deemed that they were too far off-topic and should just be deleted. These questions were very rare.

Answer (score 12):

This hearkens back to a lot of what I've been saying about certain questions - there *are* a few which can be salvaged, even if they run afoul of the community guidelines at first.

I am delighted to see this process at least get a trial run, and I'm glad to have participated in it.  That said...

### Positives

- I'm quite seriously happy about this effort.  I want to see it continue, perhaps on questions closed [with an old close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311235/1079354)?
- Allowing users with sufficient reputation to take care of the process made things fairly smooth.
- By and large, we were able to avoid groupthink and were able to objectively get these questions back in shape.

### Negatives

- Editing the main post was a bit of a nightmare.  HTML embedded directly into the list of questions meant that we had to preserve *that*, too, and every so often a missing `</i>` meant that the entire post was italicized.  (Not that this was a huge problem, but it left room for error.)  Also, conflicting edits made several editors working in concert have to wait their turn in essence until one question was moved from one section to another.
- There was some confusion as to whether or not we should edit the titles of the question *in this post*.  I did on a few, but I still feel like the system is more capable than I in handling this sort of thing (which goes back to the, "why HTML why" piece earlier).

Comment: The HTML was my fault. It was the only way to have scrollbars.

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** I have now taken the time to flag all the answers I could judge as NAA, those are now deleted. If someone else wants to have a look to evaluate the ones I skipped because I was unsure, that'd be nice.

However, the bulk of bad posts has been handled now.

---

I have to say, I'm quite unhappy with the results of the salvage-part of this effort.

First of all, there is stuff left that's still not really more than a resource request by wording, for example [Pure Java HTML viewer/renderer for use in a Scrollable pane](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2438201/3002139)

Then, you reopened stuff that is so broad that it won't get a decent answer that's not a tool/lib recommendation, like [How to serialize data in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3168863/3002139) and probably quite a few more if you look at it with fitting domain knowledge. Those questions just attract new tool-only answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44866992/3002139).

But most importantly, the answers *"that are more than just links to things"*, which supposedly exist for every reopened question, are **still buried** under a ton of answers that are exactly *"just links to things"*.

---

The first two points, while not pretty, are probably rare enough to be dealt with through normal voting, with the help of SOCVR where needed. The last one, however, is an unnecessarily big problem. I tried to solve that problem with flagging, but there are just so many answers that should be deleted that it did not seem like a reasonable solution, so eventually I gave up.

You don't really improve the situation of search results being outdated link collections if you just edit and reopen the question. You also need to get the answers that are not just links to things into the line of sight of the reader.

So please, for this and for potential future iterations: **Have a mod delete all the tool/lib-only answers from the reopened questions,** as suggested by 4castle.

Also, if in doubt, have someone with domain knowledge check if the revised question is actually answerable.

Comment: So where were you?  We could've obviously used you back then.

Comment: Gimme a gist of those that need deletion @baum and I'll see what I can do to help you.

Comment: @Makato Better late than never ;)

Comment: @Makoto That somehow slipped my attention when it was going on, I just ran into it when someone pointed out one of my [cv-pls] where reopened by SOCVR folks and Shog.

Comment: @BhargavRao Will do, thanks!