# Why are link-only answers from 5+ years ago just now appearing in the VLQ queue?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

Periodically, I'll see link-only answers from years ago appear in the VLQ queue. For example, earlier today I saw link-only answers from 2011 and 2013 appear. Why are these only showing up in the queue now? Is the site relying exclusively on people manually flagging these old posts to put them in the VLQ queue?

Comment: related: [Downvoting “marginal” posts can trigger their inclusion into Low Quality queue?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5777/31260)

Comment: I'll hazard a guess... Someone flagged them as VLQ and they went into the queue.

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, but why now when the answer's been around for years?

Comment: Because someone saw it now, decided it was VLQ, and flagged it. How else do you think it happened? I occasionally stumble across something that is really bad that's been around for quite a while that needs flagging.

Comment: rules were not strict enough back then as they are now a days.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Very likely someone flagged them, yeah.  What of it?

Those answers are probably worth the extra attention given that links could have *easily* broken in that time, and that in general, link-only answers should be dealt with.

It could *also* be due to [this recent effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run), and many answers *could* have been flagged from there.